# C++ about dynamic memory

Tags: c++

What is the difference between:

```
int myArray[5];
```

and

```
int* myArray = new int[5];
```

Comment: http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources

Comment: [Read a basic C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 6):

`int myArray[5]` is a bunch of five integers with automatic (or static) storage duration (local memory, often classified as "in stack"). Local memory gets cleared in C++ when the specific scope is exited.

`int* myArray = new int[5]` is a bunch of five integers on with dynamic storage duration (dynamic memory, often classified as "in heap"). Dynamic memory won't get cleared when the specific scope is exited (`myArray` has to be an int pointer to store the location of your dynamically created memory).

View the following example:

```
void foo(){
    int myArray[5];
}

void bar(){
    int* myArray_dynamic = new int[5];
}

int main(){
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

`foo` will use stack memory, so when `foo` returns/exits the memory will get freed automatically. However, the dynamic allocated memory, which location is stored in `myArray_dynamic` in `bar` won't get freed, as the compiler will only free the memory of `myArray_dynamic`, not the memory that's stored at its value.

This will create a memory leak, so for every use of `new` or `new[]` there has to be a call of `delete` or `delete[]` (except you are working with smart pointers, but that's for another question).

The correct version of `bar` is

```
void bar(){
    int* myArray_dynamic = new int[5];
    delete[] myArray_dynamic;
}
```

The primary reason to pick one or the other is that dynamic allocation is slower, but can be any size (automatic arrays must have a fixed compile-time size), and also that space on the stack is limited, and if you run out, [very bad things happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: Might not be on "the stack". Say "automatic or static storage duration" instead; similarly, heap is an implementation detail: say "free store" or "dynamic storage duration" instead.

Comment: Most people I know say "on the stack" to refer to automatic storage duration.  Whether it's actually on an actual stack is, as you point out, an implementation detail; we don't care one way or the other whether there's an actual stack there.  Unless you're discussing a context where the underlying implementation actually matters, saying "on the stack" is a quick and well-understand shorthand for what you actually mean.  While it may not always be the most technically correct choice of wording, it is usually the *best* choice.

Comment: @Darryl: But we don't know that the object _has_ automatic storage duration. The trap has been fallen into.

Comment: If I write this:
`void foo(){
    int myArray[5];
}`
I don't have to explicitly free `myArray`, and I say it's on the stack.  Pretty much everyone I know says the same thing.  We all know what we mean.  Whether it's actually on a stack structure is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

The first is an array that's a block of memory allocated either statically or as an automatic variable on the stack during the execution of a function ... it really depends on the context in which its declared/defined.

The second won't compile :-)

To be serious, you really want:

```
int* myArray = new int[5];
```

which means we've declared a *pointer*-type variable that points to an array of integers, and the array of integers is allocated dynamically by the C++ runtime on the heap by the call to `new`, which is a segment of memory allocated by the OS for your process to dynamically allocate variables in.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the lifetime.

`int myArray[5];`

This reserves storage for an array 5 of `int`. If `myArray` is declared at block scope, the array is discarded at the end of the block where it is declared.

```
int* myArray = new int[5];
```

This dynamically allocates an array 5 of `int`, the array exists until it is freed with  `delete []`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference

One is valid.

The other is not.

Answer (score 0):

In the second you must write

```
int* myArray = new int[5];
```

`new` retuns pointer to the  area dynamically allocated in heap.

Comment: It might not be a heap. Say "free store".